# Can not find module 'D:\R'

Tags: nestjs

I have problem when running the NestJS project as following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoizx.png)

I add the env file as well as run the command yarn install and then yarn start, but it shows the error in the image.

I had tried to remove the node_modules and re-install many and many times it but it still can not work.
However, I had switches to Ubuntu 23.04, and it works. I dont understand why it can not run the program on Windows 11.
I have no ideas and cannot find any solution related to my problem.

Comment: Did you search for `D:\R` in your project files? Maybe it is a typo somewhere.

Comment: @Clashsoft, I had searched for D:\R in my project, and there is no typo here.